# Excel 365 formula to retrieve client's newest score

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using this formula to pull the client's highest score:

```
=MAX(IF(FILTER(Appointments!G:G, Appointments!C:C=C2)>0,FILTER(Appointments!G:G,
Appointments!C:C=C2)))
```

What I want is the most recent score. Appointments!G is the score, Appointments!C is the client ID, Appointments!D is the date of the score.

Comment: Dates are numbers. Use `Max` on the date maybe?

Comment: `=MAXIFS(Appointments!G:G, Appointments!C:C,C2,Appointments!D:D,MAXIFS(Appointments!D:D,Appointments!C:C,C2))`

Comment: Also your can be simplified original: `=MAXIFS(Appointments!G:G, Appointments!C:C,C2)`

Comment: @ScottCraner I like this simplification, I'm also looking for the first lowest score that is above 0. Is there a way to write this so it excludes 0s? =MINFS(Appointments!G:G, Appointments!C:C>0, C2) didn't work

Comment: Yes, just add that to the criteria: `=MAXIFS(Appointments!G:G, Appointments!C:C,C2,Appointments!D:D,MAXIFS(Appointments!D:D,Appointments!C:C,C2,Appointments!G:G,">0"))` and `=MAXIFS(Appointments!G:G, Appointments!C:C,C2,Appointments!G:G,">0")`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you! This was very helpful, I had looked at MIN/MAXIFS earlier but hadn't quite gotten it.

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, if you share the solution in answers, with a small sample data, it will be very helpful and will be grateful as well, for future references.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the below trick of match formula.

=MATCH(1,(C2=Appointments!C:C)*
(***(MAX(FILTER(Appointments!D:D,Appointments!C:C=C2)))***=Appointments!D:D),0)

this formula will return the row index for the most recent score.

then you could combine it with the index function to get the value.

=index(Appointments!G:G,MATCH(1,(C2=Appointments!C:C)*
((MAX(FILTER(Appointments!D:D,Appointments!C:C=C2)))=Appointments!D:D),0))

the bold part is to get the most recent date:

***(MAX(FILTER(Appointments!D:D,Appointments!C:C=C2)))***